# How to optimize a fantasy sports line-up with Excel Solver

Tags: excel, mathematical-optimization, solver

I have set-up a file with player names, positions, statistics, rankings, and salaries.  I am trying to use Excel Solver (as described by @Ioannis regarding a football post from October 2013) to optimize a fantasy baseball line-up.  The issue is Excel is picking players for positions they do not play.  For example, a pitcher is being selected as the optimal outfielder in my "answer" line-up.  How do I tell Excel to recognize the positions that I've posted above each player's name in my data table so that the "answer" matches the real-life position eligibility for each player?

Thank you so much!  I'm pretty much brand new to the Solver add-in, but I'm very fascinated by it.

Drew

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Solver currently runs every player in the list (28 players) at each position (7 positions) for a total of 196 variable cells (the max is 200).  What I would prefer is for it to run 200 players (at 1 position each) for a total of 200 variable cells (aka the maximum).  My table goes from C4:AD10 with the player name in row 3 and their position in row 2 (directly above the data table).  B4:B10 also lists the positions that are required in the line-up (one position per row).  The requirements are 1 SP, 1 C, 1 1B, 1 2B, 1 3B, 1 SS, and 3 OF for a total of 9 players.  A player can only be used once.

Comment: What you describe is an additional set of constraints. The typical way to incorporate such constraints is to have a binary matrix of player names as rows and positions as columns. A 1 in any `(player,position)` pair should denote the position of that particular player. Then you should have formulas that link the binary player variables with the number of players used in each position. Think about the spreadsheet design carefully, because it might become messy. For more than 200 variables you might want to check [SolverStudio](http://solverstudio.org/) or [OpenSolver](http://opensolver.org/).

Comment: You can take it from there I guess? If you give us more details, (how your spreadsheet is design, your efforts etc), I will work on this to post a full response. Good luck!

Comment: Ioannis, I was hoping you would see this :)  Thank you.  I haven't ramped up my number of variables yet, but perhaps I will try the OpenSolver download.  I trust it's safe if you're recommending it.  As for the position issue, my solution (for now) was to list the players by position (SP, SP, SP, SP, OF, OF, OF, OF, etc.) and then I only selected the cells where they are eligible to play (the (player, position) 1 that you referred to) for the cell reference that Solver can manipulate in order to reach my objective.  It works for now on a small amount of players.

Comment: Glad that this worked out for you! If you have some time, feel free to post it as an answer and accept it so that it can help others. Yes, what I suggested may sound like an overkill, but it is the way to go if you have players with multiple positions eligibility I guess (Unless you make "copies" of the same players and then restrict them to be equal in the math program). Thats the beauty of multiple formulations!

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is an additional set of constraints. The typical way to incorporate such constraints is to have a binary matrix of player names as rows and positions as columns. A 1 in any (player,position) pair should denote the position of that particular player. Then you should have formulas that link the binary player variables with the number of players used in each position. Think about the spreadsheet design carefully, because it might become messy. For more than 200 variables you might want to check SolverStudio or OpenSolver. –  Ioannis